# after moving template to another DS : unable to create VM from this template

Tags: vmware-esxi

Any idea why after moving template to another DS, then I am  unable to create VM from this template?

Only workaround is :

1. convert template to VM
2. storage vMotion this VM to another DS
3. convert VM to template

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiwH1.jpg

Q2:
Why moving template to another DS take 10x more time then vMotion Storage ?

Comment: No real answer here sorry but moving files/directories via the web-client can be a bit unreliable, often to do with firewall ports - it can be slow too - same goes for via scp or similar - I've never really got my head around why this isn't just black and white (works/doesn't work) but I know if we sort out the firewall ports it often springs into life. Sorry for such a vague comment.

Comment: "moving template to another DS" I meant using Vcenter option, not via any extra tool.

Comment: ok, understand, we have a lot of people come here going the other way, hope you get a proper answer